# Log is printing different string than what it showing using Toast method

Tags: android, logging, barcode-scanner, android-toast

I am trying to get the string from the barcode reader. In my case, I have the Honeywell barcode reader.

Actual String: 10008-3TE40M181446-183A-976R

But when I am showing this with toast method it is previewing as same i.e. 10008-3TE40M181446-183A-976R

But when I trying to print on the console using log function it prints as
10008-3��TE40��M181446-183��A-9767��R

Code to read barcode string:

```
if (e.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            char pressedKey = (char) e.getUnicodeChar();
            barcode += pressedKey;


            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && !Check.isEmpty(barcode.toString())) {
                showToastInCenter(barcode);
                searchByBarcode(barcode.trim());
                barcode = "";


                return true;

            }
        }
```

}

```
public void showToastInCenter(String message){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, gmessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**EDIT:**

As [this link](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD) suggested
� is REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

As I have read other stack overflow answer which says if UTF-8 is not able to detect any char then it will replace with this "replacement char". 
Maybe string has ISO-8889-1 character set.

But now the question comes how will I convert this to UTF-8 character set.

Comment: Please add your **showToastInCenter** code

Comment: @RaviMakvana added

Comment: why would you ever use `Toast` for debug logging?

Comment: @pskink that is just for debug purpose only, I also try to put LOG but i was gettting different result that i have mentioned earlier too

Comment: `Toast` shold not be used tfor any debug purposes - this is `Log` class that is designed for

Comment: @pskink that i know, I was just checking do I get the wrong data format in toast or not

Comment: @Ankur_009 what is type of barcode key is that a String?

Comment: yes that is string @RaviMakvana

Comment: @Ankur_009 where did you added this code on EditText KeyListener?

Comment: nops dispatchKeyEvent @RaviMakvana